# Why does this SSH client use "zDonez"?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am working on an application that will get files on a server via SFTP, using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

There isn't much documentation, but I found this (french) blog post: [Un client SSH pour Java](http://developpef.blogspot.com/2010/09/javajsch-un-client-ssh-pour-java.html).

I just can figure out what the `TERMINATOR` variable is for:

```
private static final String TERMINATOR = "zDonez";
```

Why does this use `"zDonez"`?

Comment: Actually, a short Google search of `zDonez` shows [SSH Over Java](http://blog.james-carr.org/2006/07/11/ssh-over-java/), which explains what is going on here. (This also seems to be the origin of this code, and it is in English.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"zDonez" is an arbitrary string that won't appear in the output of any of the commands you run. If it does, you need to select another value for TERMINATOR.
The purpose of it is to detect when a command has finished running.

Answer (score 1):

As Klas already said, in this case `zDonez` is simply a string which will be printed by the remote shell after the original command was executed.

```
command += "; echo \"" + TERMINATOR + "\" \n";
```

By this way the `getServerResponse()` method can know when the command is finished, and return the right string.

I would say that this is not the best use of the `shell` channel type, which should only be used for interactive use, i.e. when a user is there to decide when to input the next command. (Most shells have a prompt for this reason.)

A better way would be to use an individual `exec` channel for each command (or series of commands), though then you can't use `cd` or similar state-changing commands, as each exec channel will have its own shell.

---

For SFTP, you don't need to execute remote commands at all - use an [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) instead of an `exec` or `shell` channel. There is the [`Sftp`](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java) example in the default JSch distribution, which shows how to use about any of the operations supported by this class.

More general documentation is in the [JSch Manual in the wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Manual).

(Disclaimer: I wrote this [inofficial JSch Javadoc](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html) (based on the official sources), and also most of the text in the Wiki Manual).